# Прошу прощениЕ или прощениЯ?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Как правильно писать и говорить: *прошу прощени**е*** или *прошу прощени**я**?*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Может быть, стоит добавить метку "управление", а орфографию поменять на грамматику? Как Вы считаете, Артём? Так все красиво — без Вашего согласия не хочется влезать.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: ну Вы засмущали меня! Как будто я тут главный.)) Да, по-моему, Вы всё правильно предлагаете. ;) Сам над метками просто редко задумываюсь над чужими.

Answer (score 3):

Конечно же, правильно: *прошу прощени**я**.*

Прошу чего, а не что. Просить что-то, а не чего-то, можно только в сочетании с конкретными существительными, как видно из Римминой ссылки.

Другой пример: *дай день**ги*** (200 рублей, о которых договорились раньше), но *дай ден**ег*** (сколько-то или достаточное на что-то количество).

Answer (score 2):

[Прошу прощени**я**](https://phraseology.academic.ru/10113/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
В речевом этикете: употребляется при обращении или предупреждении о чём-либо или как извинение за сказанное, сделанное.

*Прошу* (чего? Р. п.) *прощени**я*** — выражение считается разговорным, оно неизменно. Это своеобразная формула извинения, любезности.

*— Сюда, сюда давайте! — негромко крикнул им капитан и виновато сказал собравшимся: — Задержался, прошу прощения* (В. Быков).

*— У меня сейчас нет времени заниматься пустяками, — резко ответил мой сосед, но тут же с улыбкой добавил: — Прошу прощения за грубость* (А. К. Дойл).

В словаре управления:
[просить](https://upravlenie.academic.ru/2062/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) (попросить) *чего, что, о ком-чем* и *за кого.*
**1. чего** (при сочетании с существительными отвлеченными или конкретными, но употребленными с оттенком неопределенности). *Просить помощи. **Просить прощения.** Просить слова на собрании. Просить денег* (неопределенное количество).

Answer (score -1):

Конечно же, вопрос был с подвохом. В реальности можно писать и так и так. Все ваши апелляции к родительному падежу устарели, как борода Льва Толстого.

Более скажу, в устоявшиеся современной практике "прошу прощения" читается очень "криво". "Прошу прощение" звучит более лаконично.
И просят как и "ЧЕГО", так и "ЧТО". Причем просят "ЧТО" гораздо чаще.

Comment: Бесподобно! _Устарели, как борода Льва Толстого?_ Она — вечна. А на **достойные** примеры из устоявшейся современной практики хотелось бы,  конечно, посмотреть. Поделитесь, пожалуйста, своими неперекисшими знаниями.

Comment: "*В реальности можно писать и так, и так.*" — чем докажите?

Comment: Каким образом "прошу прощение" звучит "более лаконично, если оба варианта на слух почти неразличимы? Да и вам вообще знакомо значение слова "лаконично"?